# Invalid SQL Syntax error

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

Few weeks ago my code was all fine, but recently I've been unable to load my test database on my web app (built using CakePhp).

This is the error :

> Warning (512): SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near ') LEFT JOIN `blogs` AS `Blog` ON
>   (`Song`.`blog_id` = `Blog`.`id`)  WHERE 1 = 1' at line 1
>   [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 684]

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM `songs` AS `Song` 
LEFT JOIN libraries AS `Library` ON (`Song`.`id` = `Library`.`song_id` AND `Library`.`user_id` =) 
LEFT JOIN `blogs` AS `Blog` ON (`Song`.`blog_id` = `Blog`.`id`) 
WHERE 1 = 1
```

> Warning (512): SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near ')  WHERE 1 = 1   ORDER BY `Song`.`postdate`
>   desc  LIMIT 100' at line 1
>   [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 684]

```
SELECT *, Blog.id 
FROM `songs` AS `Song` 
LEFT JOIN libraries AS `Library` ON (`Song`.`id` = `Library`.`song_id` AND `Library`.`user_id` =) 
WHERE 1 = 1 
ORDER BY `Song`.`postdate` DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a condition for the Library.userid column:

```
Library.user_id =)
```

You need to specify a value on the right side of the equals sign!

Answer (score 2):

your error is here:

```
Library.user_id =)
```

maybe you want to change it to:

```
Library.user_id ='$user_id')
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that some value for `user_id` is not being passed into the query:

```
`Library`.`user_id` =)
//-----------------^^^^
```

Likely, there is some PHP variable missing here, or a PDO parameter is not being correctly bound.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `songs` AS `Song` 
left JOIN libraries AS `Library` 
ON (`Song`.`id` = `Library`.`song_id` AND `Library`.`user_id` =) <-- HERE's something missing
LEFT JOIN `blogs` AS `Blog` ON (`Song`.`blog_id` = `Blog`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1

SELECT *, 
Blog.id FROM `songs` AS `Song` left JOIN libraries AS `Library` 
ON (`Song`.`id` = `Library`.`song_id` AND `Library`.`user_id` =) <-- HERE's something missing
WHERE 1 = 1 ORDER BY `Song`.`postdate` desc LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a CakePHP question, my answer will approach from the paradigms of the framework.  However, given your SQL output, you are either NOT using CakePHP or you are doing something that is definitely a no-no.

Please post the Find statement that you are using the build this SQL statement and your `Library`'s `hasMany` relationship to `Blog`. Unless you are using the query method, I think you would get a PHP error before you could build this type of SQL statement using the CakePHP find conventions.  If you are using the `query` method to find your data, then don't.  This is a simple query that can be done with CakePHP find easily.

Your library model should like like:

```
public $hasMany => array('Blog');
```

And the find:

```
$this->Library->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            '1' => 1 //Not sure why you have Where 1=1
        )
        'order' => "Library.name DESC",
        'limit' => 100
    )
);
```